# Как растянуть содержимое контейнера от шапки и до футера?

Tags: html, css

Прошу сразу не кидаться в меня тапками со словами, что это боянистый вопрос и мне просто лень лезть в гугл. Вообщем облазив пару страниц гугла, решения я так и не нашел.  Суть вопроса, как растянуть в подобной структуре таблицу до футера

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="navbar" style="font-size:0;line-height:0;"></div>
        </div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="content_table" width="1030">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebord left_s top_left"><img height="100" src={{=URL('static','images/top_left.png')}} width="16"></td>
                    <td class="content" rowspan="3">ТутБудет тело вухахаха<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        Aggg
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidebord right_s top_right"><img height="100" src={{=URL('static','images/top_right.png')}} width="16"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebord left_s">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="sidebord right_s">&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidebord left_s"><div class="bottom_left" position><img height="100" src={{=URL('static','images/bottom_left.png')}} width="16"></div></td>
                    <td class="sidebord right_s "><div class="bottom_right" position><img height="100" src={{=URL('static','images/bottom_right.png')}} width="16"></div></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <img height="150" src={{=URL('static','images/footer.png')}} width="1000">
    </div>
</body>
```

а вот css

```
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
}
#content_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100%
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#wrapper {
    background: green;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin: -150px auto 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1032px;
}
#header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 150px;
}
html,
body {
    );
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image:url("{{=URL('static','images/main_background.png");}}
}
pre {
    margin: 0px;
}
#footer {
    background: blue;
    border-top: 0px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: может переверстать блочно?

Comment: Блочные элементы по вертикали не растягиваются

Comment: @nMike, ты серьёзно?

Answer (score 2):

У тебя ошибка в css.

```
#content_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100%
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Ты забыл точку с запятой. С ней всё сработает.

Comment: Нет не помогло, все равно не растягиваеться

Answer (score 0):

Три простых способа растягивания main между шапкой и футером.

1. Если известны высоты header и footer

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body * {
  background: rgb(169, 209, 245);
  margin: 5px;
}

header {
  height: 30px;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}

footer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

2. С помощью `display: flex`

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

body * {
  background: rgb(169, 209, 245);
}

header {
  height: 100px;
}

main {
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

3. С помощью grid. Это уже [сами читайте](https://tuhub.ru/posts/css-grid-complete-guide).